# JTOpen JobList filter multiple job names

Tags: ibm-midrange, jtopen

I'm trying to modify current code such that a JobList.addJobSelectionCriteria using SELECTION_JOB_NAME can take wildcards - is this possible?

Documentation for JobList.html#SELECTION_JOB_NAME indicates that the filter String can be "A generic name." - what does this mean exactly?

The current jobs names I need to query can be represented by a Java regex like "JOB.RUN|JOB.PROCESS" - but I can't get that to work with addJobSelectionCriteria and I'm trying to minimize job names in the application configuration and also do the filtering on the JobList query itself.

Even though I can do a filtering post-query, the time it takes to process a large number of jobs is an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not looked at the docs [to which no link was given], but the ***generic***-name capability for the Qualified JOB() Name, on/at the server, is effected by omission of the values for Job.Number and/or the Job.User; i.e. the Job.Name is required, and if that is the only value specified, then all jobs with that name, irrespective the Job.User and Job.Number qualifiers, will be searched -- the search is aspecific for user and number, thus is generic to those elements.  If a Job.User and Job.Name are specified, then all jobs with those specific qualifiers are searched, irrespective the Job.Number; the search is generically inclusive of all job numbers for the specified user-name and job-name.

Typically the term *generic name* on the server means a *name* prefix, for which the `*` asterisk character as suffix suggests searching across all values with that name-as-prefix; one or a few interfaces may allow for prepending an asterisk for a similar purpose, but typically the *other* form of a generic specification is by a *special value* such as *ALL to indicate there is no filtering, or something like for examples, either token *ALLEXEC used to filter by inclusion of only *EXECutable* variants of what is being searched or token *PGM used to filter by inclusion [or if on an OMIT() specification, then filter by omission] of only *Program Objects*.  The qualified job name is atypical, such that the aforementioned as-typical-generics are **disallowed** on any of the **JOB** parameter of the Commands on the server, best I can recall.

**04-Oct-2016 addendum**:

For a reference on the more generic [pun intended] usage of the term **generic name**, of the server vernacular, the following Help Text from the TYPE parameter of the Parameter (PARM) command, used to define the type of parameter as a *name* that allows a generic* specification.  Note: I could find no explicit definition of the term within the Toolbox docs, just the references, but I did find an example of an OS Command (CMD) with a Job (JOB) parameter that also allows the same **generic name** specifications [user-name and job-name elements], and that is the Start Database Monitor (STRDBMON) command:

> ```
>                  Type of value (TYPE) - Help
> ```
>
> *GENERIC
>       The parameter value is a character string that represents a
>       generic name.  A generic name contains one or more characters
>       followed by an asterisk (*) and must conform to the rules for
>       generic names.  The name identifies a group of objects whose
>       names all begin with the characters preceding the asterisk (*).
>       If an asterisk (*) is not included, the system assumes that the
>       generic name is a complete object name.

Comment: Thanks, I was referring to the javadoc documentations for jtopen here:

https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/iseries/v5r2/ic2924/info/rzahh/javadoc/com/ibm/as400/access/JobList.html#SELECTION_JOB_NAME

Comment: I didn't specifically test the JT400 class, however the System i Navigator included in IBM i Access for Windows uses Java and it's job screens do support `MYJOB*`.  Though the green screen `WRKJOB` command does not.

Answer (score 2):

"Generic name" on the IBM i is a simple wildcard, not a reg-ex.

```
MYJOB*
```

Would find any job with a name that starts out MYJOB.  eg: MYJOB1, MYJOB2, MYJOBEOM.

Note: for the most part, when providing a generic name on the IBM i, the wildcard symbol * has to be at the end.  So you can't look for objects ending with a certain pattern.